# How to split up a js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem where I can't upload a js file to GitHub because it is too large. Is there a way to split it into multiple smaller files that still work in the same way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting the file, use Git LFS

https://git-lfs.github.com/